# Select all but rows which match across two tables in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**What I'm trying to do**

I have two tables, one for events, and one that says whether each event id has been seen. I want to create a query that joins both tables on *event.id* and *seen.eventid*. However, I would only like to return the rows which have *not* been seen, ordered by how recent they are.

**What I have right now**

This is the query which works for returning all the events which have already been seen:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events`
JOIN `seen` ON (`seen`.`event_id`=`event`.`id`)
    //This is not part of the question but I might as well paste the entire code
    //WHERE `user_id`='34'
    //AND (`meta_id`='45' OR `meta_id`='37' OR `meta_id`='43')
GROUP BY `event_id`
ORDER BY `event`.`date` DESC
```

How do I reverse the query so that those returned are the rows in `event` that are *not* matched by this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know your table structures so I'm just guessing...

```
SELECT *
  FROM events e
  LEFT
  JOIN seen s
    ON s.event_id = e.id)
   AND s.user_id=34
 WHERE e.meta_id IN (45,37,43)
   AND s.event_id IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY e.event_id
 ORDER 
    BY e.date DESC
```

Comment: Perfect. Had to add in an open parenthesis before `s.event_id = e.id)` but other than that it's flawless. And great presentation. Thanks for this

Comment: You can remove those parentheses. Either way.